# Get value of css resized element

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize

What I want is I can get the values of a `CSS` shape that has been resized by the user using the `CSS` resize property. Is there a way to get the value of the `CSS` shape once it has been resized by the user with plain `JavaScript`? It should work for both quadrilaterals and curved shapes. I am new to programming.
My code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<style>
#resizeable-shape{
height:7vh; width:7vh; background-color:blue; resize:both; overflow:auto; border-radius:50%;
</style>
<div id="resizeable-shape"></div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you meant `dimensions` by `values`. So, if it is true, then please find the code given below for the same:

### **Code explained**

I have used the `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` properties to get the width and height of the shape. Then, I used an `if` statement that says- If the height and width are not `40px`, then alert the dimensions of the shape.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var shape = document.getElementById("resizeable-shape");
  var width = shape.offsetWidth;
  var height = shape.offsetHeight;
  if (width !== 40 || height !== 40) {
    alert("Width: " + width + "px \n" + "Height: " + height + "px");
  }
}
```

```css
#resizeable-shape {
  height:40px; 
  width:40px; 
  background-color:blue; 
  resize:both; 
  overflow:auto; 
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<div id="resizeable-shape" onclick="myFunction()"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: shyamath seth Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it possible to get the dimensions in the vh measurement?

Comment: The `offsetHeight` and `offsetWidth` properties come in pixels by default. So, unfortunately, you can't get them in vh measurement.